# Wording a phrase: Explaining opinion, relativity, and perspective

Tags: phrase-request

What is a good way to word an after thought pointing out that, "what one person might view as being art, another might not"?

Answer (score 2):

There is a saying: "Beauty is in the eye of the beholder".

Answer (score 0):

What about "**After all, art is a matter of perspective.**" then you use an arty word - perspective and you get over your point.